# how to add standard elements in php in one line

Tags: php, html

I have created a few php files Following are their names:

1. standard_head.php (which contains basic standard html code)
2. header.php
3. navbar.php
4. sidebar.php
5. footer.php
6. standard_footer.php (which contains closing html tags)

Page content will vary in every page and would also include html content.

I am trying to create a lot of php pages which will use all of the above pages directly.

Now I can use them directly using include statement for each of them, but I was wondering if it was possible to include all of them together with one just statement ?

```
<?php include('../includes/standard_head.php'); ?>
        <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
                <div id="content">
                <!-- my page content -->
                </div> <!-- end #content -->
                <?php include('includes/sidebar.php'); ?>
            </div> <!-- End #wrapper -->
        <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/standard_footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could so this (note that this is a very basic example and that I wouldn't use this myself without taking into account meta tags, page titles etc.)

**template.php**

```
<?php include('../includes/standard_head.php'); ?>

<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>

            <div id="content">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            <!-- my page content -->
            </div> <!-- end #content -->

        <?php include('includes/sidebar.php'); ?>

    </div> <!-- End #wrapper -->

    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>

<?php include('../includes/standard_footer.php'); ?>
```

Then, on a page (say index.php, for example):

**index.php**

```
<?php
$content = '<h1>Welcome</h1>';
include 'template.php';
?>
```

P.S: If you go down this route, make sure that you check out the [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) first.

Comment: This makes sense. I can dynamically create page title so I should be able to use it the same way as $content and I'll see if I need to change meta tags but in my case I don't think I really need to worry about them. I'll try and see if it works.

Comment: oh but in this case I'll need to use php to generate all the content which means I'll need to use something like echo '<div>'; if I want to use any other html statement. I think it would make it more mundane. I'll edit the question slightly to include the fact that I might need to include html in page content also.

Comment: @user1439090 Check out the link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: This is not a very good solution since content needs to be stored in string in order to display it. You could use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() but it would lead to very bad code.

Comment: @kustrle That's why I linked to the Output Control Functions, which include ob_start and ob_get_clean.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, it isn't best practice to use them in every single script that needs to be rendered in template

Answer (score 0):

Just create a PHP file that has a list of them i.e.

```
<?php include("this file"); 
      include("the other file");
?>
```

And then just add that file.

Comment: I can add all of them in one file but then how will I add page content after nav.php?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but you could use a template engine like Twig.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try using more complex template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or some MVC framework like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) (this is not required but would allow you to create complex sources more easily) and then build script like this:

```
<?php include('../includes/standard_head.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
            <div id="content">
                <?php echo $menu->getCustomEntries(); ?>
            </div>
```

Where `$menu` will be your custom object containing methods for displaying menus and submenus...

Answer (score -1):

There is no straight way to include multiple files, as include / require functions except only one argument. though you can use following logic.

`#include_all_files.php
include('../includes/standard_head.php');
include('includes/header.php');
...

## use above file in other files

include('includes/include_all_files.php');
`

Comment: If there is `html` content in the files, it will completely mess up the formatting.